# What's the proper way to use reflection to instantiate objects of unknown classes at runtime?

Tags: java, reflection

I am working on a Configuration Loader class so that I can change the parameters of my program via an external text file (config.txt) rather than having to recompile my code with every change I make.

It has been suggested that I use Java's Reflection to do this, but I'm a little confused as to how I might actually implement this.

I have been able to successfully extract the class name and the arguments for its constructor from my text file, but how do I go from this to an instantiated object?

here's what I have of my method so far:

```
public void loadObject(String classString, HashMap hm)
  {
  String className = props.getProperty(classString);
  Class c = Class.forName(className);
  }
```

classString is a string containing the name of the class, and hm is a hashmap where the class' constructor parameters map to their intended values.

I.e., for `class Foo (int xPos, float yPos)`, "xPos" would map to a string of the intended int, and "yPos" maps to a string of the intended float. I **want** to be able to return, `new Foo(hm.get"xPos".toInt, hm.get"yPost".toFloat)`, but I'm unsure how to dynamically use a constructor like that (the issue is, there are multiple possible classes -- perhaps it's a `bar` instead of a `foo`, for instance).

I know that its possible to do an if/else based off the classString, and simply call the proper constructor after identifying it that way, but I am looking to create a more extensible code that doesn't have to be rewritten every time I add a new class to the program.

All  of the possible objects inherit from a single parent object.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You would use `Class.getConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes)` to get a reference to the constructor followed by `Constructor.newInstance(Object... initargs)`.

However I would suggest taking a look at a dependency injection framework such as Spring or Guice as it sounds like what you are creating is a basic version of what they do.

**Upon request for expanding this answer:**

```
Class c = Class.forName(name);
Constructor ctor = c.getConstructor(Integer.class, Integer.class);
Integer param1 = hm.get("xPos") ...;
Integer param2 = hm.get("yPos") ...;
Object instanceOfTheClass = ctor.newInstance(param1, param2);
```

Of course instead of `param1` and `param2` you would create an array of arguments based upon what was in the input file (the same goes for the arguments to `getConstructor()`), etc.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the first line of your pseudocode. I'm not familiar with Reflection at all, so I'm not sure what it is your code is actually *doing*. Would it be possible to expand your answer a little?

Comment: Oh, okay, so, to follow my example above, Foo.GetConstructor would return an array of (int, float) ? And then from there I could properly cast objects into the initargs for Constructor.newInstance?

Comment: @RavenDreamer, no. You would call getConstructor on the Class reference, passing in the argument types. On the instance of Constructor returned, you would then invoke newInstance(arguments). I'll add this to my answer

Comment: I had to do getConstructor(int.class, int.class) in my project. I was trying to get a constructor of this form: new A(int x, int y). Integer.class was throwing an error. Turns out Integer.class != int.class

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of doing it from program arguments:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.*;

public class InstantiateWithReflectionIncludingArgs {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String className = args[0];
        List<Object> argList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        if (args.length > 1) {
            argList.addAll(Arrays.asList(args).subList(1, args.length));
        }
        Class c = Class.forName(className);
        List<Class<?>> argTypes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        for (Object arg : argList) {
            argTypes.add(arg.getClass());
        }
        Constructor constructor = c.getConstructor(
            argTypes.toArray(new Class<?>[argTypes.size()]));
        Object o = constructor.newInstance(
            argList.toArray(new Object[argList.size()]));
        System.out.println("Created a " + o.getClass() + ": " + o);
    }
}
```

Naturally, the `argList` can only ever have Strings in this case because they're pulled from a `String[]`, but you could add args of any type. Note that constructor args are positional, not named, so the names in the map won't do you much good. They need to be in the proper order.

Try running it and passing "java.util.Date" as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
Class<?> clazz = MyClass.class;
Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor( /* Array of Classes the constructor takes */);
ctor.newInstance( /* arguments the constructor takes */ );
```