# Define object of a class derived from a string variable

Tags: class, variables, object, declaration

Following is the use case:

Invoker class (with main method)

```
public class Invoker {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
          String class_file="Batch_Status";
      }
}
```

Class to be invoked (with the same method name as that of class name, e.g. in this case it is Batch_Status)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Batch_Status {

    public static void Batch_Status(String args) {

     ......
     ......Code Goes Here
     ......   

    }
}
```

Now the problem is that i am not able to define any object such as test in Invoker class by using the value of string class_file such as class_file test = new class_file();

Above is just a snippet, in my production code the values in the String variable will vary and for each value, a different class file (the name of the class file will be same as that of value of the String variable).

Please suggest.

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate:[What's the proper way to use reflection to instantiate objects of unknown classes at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7698237/2033671)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code demonstrates being able to retrieve a class instance given a string:

```
String classString = "com.rbs.testing.Test";
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(classString);
        Test test = (Test) c.newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you don't know what class to cast to yet, you can dump

```
c.newInstance();
```

into an Object class, then use if else clauses until you find out the class type contained in the object.

```
Object o =  c.newInstance();
if (o instanceof Test) {
} else if(o instanceof Test2) {
```

I hope this helps. Sorry if I misunderstood your need.

Comment: Glad I could help @VishalGarg! If it's not too much, kindly accept the answer please, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michael,

In fact, while doing some brainstorming, i also did the same thing and it worked as desired. Now  i am able to call the method as well which is also derived from the same string variable. Following is the code which i tried:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

import java.util.logging.*;
public class Invoker {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
            String str ="Batch_Status";
            Class t = Class.forName(str);
            t.getMethods()[0].invoke(t,str);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Invoker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

And when checked your reply, it seems to be quite similar. Thanks, i really appreciate that.

Regards