# Use reflection to create a dynamic object of a Class with Parameterized constructor

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, reflection, junit

I have a enum of that has locator,classname.

```
public enum listofclasses{
    note(By.css(".notes", "NotesPage"),
    document(By.css".docs", DocumentsPage");
}

Public NotesPage a extends BasecustomerPage{
    public a(BasePage owningPage){
    }

    public pageisdisplayed(){
    }
}
```

when i Am running the test with Junit my test has to create dynamic object of the class based on string passed.

```
@Test
public class test(){
    for(listofclasses list : listofclasses.values ){
        String className = getclass(list);

        Class<?> cls = Class.forName(className);
        Object clsInstance = (Object) cls.newInstance();
    }
```

How do I get the parameterized constructor and access the methodsof the class

Comment: This might help you 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful

Comment: You’ll probably want to start by reading the [documentation for Class.getConstructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-).  To learn how to use a Constructor object, follow the appropriate links in that documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the proper way to use reflection to instantiate objects of unknown classes at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698237/whats-the-proper-way-to-use-reflection-to-instantiate-objects-of-unknown-classe)